# Java equivalent for C++'s "std::string::find_first_of"

Tags: java, android

is there any Java equivalent for C++'s "std::string::find_first_of"?

```
 string string1( "This is a test string!");
 int location = string1.find_first_of( "aeiou" );
 //location is now "2" (the position of "i")
```

what is the easiest way to achieve this same functionality?

edit: also the proposed solution have to work for Android.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without the use of an external library:

```
     String string = "This is a test string!";
     String letters = "aeiou";
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[" + letters + "]");
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
     int position = -1;
     if (matcher.find()) {
         position = matcher.start();
     }
     System.out.println(position); // prints 2
```

Comment: Thank you. I'd use this suggestion, as i do not need to add an external library.

Comment: @AngelKoh Also, for efficiency, you should reuse the pattern instead of creating one every time (unless the `letters` change each time of course).

Answer (score 5):

Not the most efficient but simple:

```
String s = "This is a test string!";
String find = "[aeiou]";
String[] tokens = s.split(find);
int index = tokens.length > 1 ? tokens[0].length() : -1; //-1 if not found
```

Note: the `find` string must not contain any reserved regex character, such as `.*[]` etc.

Comment: A quick efficiency improvement here might be to pass a limit of 2 to split, e.g: `String[] tokens = s.split(find,2);`

Answer (score 5):

Using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com):

```
CharMatcher.anyOf("aeiou").indexIn("This is a test string!");
```

(`CharMatcher` lets you manipulate character classes somewhat more flexibly than the Apache `StringUtils` alternative, e.g. providing constants like `CharMatcher.DIGIT` and `CharMatcher.WHITESPACE`, letting you complement, union, intersect, etc. character classes...)

Answer (score 1):

use StringUtils.indexOfAny , here is a link for you http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html