# How do I check to see if a string has any numbers?

Tags: java

So I am supposed to create a method which checks to see if a string contains any numbers. It will return "yes" if it does and "no" if it does not. I think I have done everything correct so far, but am not sure how to use the indexOf() to search for any number ranging from 0 - 9. Please note I am a beginner in javascript, so I would appreciate beginner friendly responses.

```
String go( String a  ) 
{
    int x = a.indexOf( ??? );
    {
      if (x == -1)
      {
        return "no";
      }
      else
      {
        return "yes";
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using regex

Comment: To use `indexOf()` you will need to check each digit character individually. Sounds like you need a loop.

Comment: My bad, I am extremely new and couldn't even tell that there was a difference.

Comment: @LeNitro Now you know. Welcome to the world of programming!

Comment: Is this java or javascript? They are very different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While C++ has a function that's quite suitable for searching for any of several specified chars, in java one must check for each char.

[Java equivalent for C++'s "std::string::find_first_of"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370312/java-equivalent-for-cs-stdstringfind-first-of)

If you wish to instead use indexOf, note that it returns -1 if char is not present.  You are on the right track, but need to search for each of them.

java:

```
public boolean hasNum(String s) {
  for(char num = '0'; num <= '9'; num=num+1) {
    if(s.indexOf(num) != -1) return true;
  }
  return false; //none of them were found so we got here
}
```

Comment: This is quite an inefficient implementation. Instead, walk from left to right through the string and check the char at hand against the chars you are searching. Also, Java, like C++ does have a way to do this. Look into `Matcher`. Alternative, a limited split, like `split(..., 2)`.

Comment: Also note that OP doesnt seem to need the index. So a simple `matches(...)` will do the trick as well.

Comment: I believe matcher is covered in the link to the java 'equivalent' It's not as convenient as C++ but I do agree it's superior to indexOf.  The indexOf example is simply provided to address OP's "how to use the indexOf()".  Please post your simple solution as an answer and OP can choose what he was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can match your string s1 with this regex which checks if there is one or more digits in the string.

```
boolean hasDigit = s1.matches(".*\\d+.*");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public String checkNumbers(String text) {
    return text.matches(".*\\d+.*") ? "yes" : "no";
}
```

Comment: Please add some context why you think this is a useful answer. See also [answer].